# Run greasemonkey script after javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to modify a variable - which is created in javascript - and run a function to change some visual stuff on a page. But my greasemonkey script is - i guess - running before the javascript, i'm getting an error says function is not defined.

How can I force to run my script after the javascript runs?

Actually what I'm trying to do is very simple. There is a variable called cursort, what I want to do is change that to "data-price" and sort the list again using updateSort(). Here is the code:

```
var cursort = "data-price";
updateSort();
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar, there was a object defined at the end of the page that I wanted to just cancel out, so it's functions wouldn't run (it captured link clicks and ran some stuff).
In the page it was defined like this:

```
var someObj = { ... }
```

I made a greasemonkey script (after much trial/error) that looked like this.

```
window.addEventListener ("load", runAfter, false);
function runAfter() {
    unsafeWindow.someObj = null;
}
```

Now clicking on the links does not trigger all the other actions that were in someObj.

Maybe you can do something like that?

Comment: This is exactly what i've tried. It perfectly made sense, but it does not work for some reason.